# Why I Unable To Logout In My App?

Tags: android

About App:

1. There Is a TabActivity which have 5 child Activity(Say A,B,C,D,E)
2. There is A top bar in Application which Have also 5 option(Say ta,tb,tc,td,te)
3. when click te top menu a dropdown list open(Which is activity as a dialog ) contains all  application option including Logout.
4. When I click logout it is going on login screen but if press back button, Tab child Activity open [Say move from B (which is childeActivity of Tab to any ) --> Normal Activity(This have top bar) ] in this Activity if user press logout.
   Login screen open but if press back B is open. I have try 3 method till now plz anyone suggest me I have been tried these way which is not working for me:

1 -

```
objeditor.putString(AppConstants.USER_ID,"");
objeditor.commit();
Intent i=new Intent(MoreActivity.this, Login.class);//use ApplicationContext() as well  
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

2 -

```
Intent i=new Intent(MoreActivity.this, Login.class);
for(int index=0;index<AppConstants.objactivity.size();index++)
{
    if(AppConstants.objactivity!=null && AppConstants.objactivity.get(index)!=null)
    {
        AppConstants.objactivity.get(index).finish();   
    }
}
AppConstants.objactivity.clear();
startActivity(i);
```

please anyone suggest me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MoreActivity.this, LoginActivity.class)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK ));
finish();
```